# Good Introduction to Mathematical Analysis Book.

Tags: analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I was ask to teach Mathematical Analysis this semester. I just want to ask if you can recommend a good reference material for Introductory Mathematical Analysis subject. Currently I am planning to use Mathematical Analysis by Tom Apostol. Aside from this book can you recommend other book that can possibly be used? thanks in advance Sirs and Mams.

Comment: There are lots of similar questions here already: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/teaching-introductory-real-analysis, etc.

Comment: It really depends on many things: the student level, the course syllabus, the program (engineering or science), university or high school etc. If you supplied more information it would be possible to provide better suggestions.

Comment: Hi @A.G. the level is undergraduate mathematics. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Hans for the links.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good book for self study of a First Course in Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62212/good-book-for-self-study-of-a-first-course-in-real-analysis)

Answer (score 2):

"Introductory Real Analysis" - Kolmogorov and Fomin.

It covers almost everything students need to know about set theory, metric spaces, topological spaces, linear spaces, functionals and operators, measure, integrations, differentiation. This book covered everything I learned in 3 semesters of real analysis.

Comment: I have no clue which book is really good though, that is what my lecturer recommended me, so I bought it and used it for exam preparation.

Comment: Hi @Tesla thanks for your answer. I just wondering if you know a book that caters purely mathematical analysis since we have both real and complex analysis. Thanks. An upvote though for your answer. thanks a lot. I will try to find the book you recommend.